# invalidargument=value of '11' is not valid for 'index'

Tags: vb.net, listview

I actually don't know what's wrong, I'm trieng to make a ListView and get a subitem's text of it.

the error occurred here:

> Dim l As String = ListView2.Items(i).SubItems.Item(11).Text

i = 0 cause it's in the For loop, and that item should be "A." and I want the twelfth column so I take nr 11, but it says "invalidargument=value of '11' is not valid for 'index'".

Note:
Program is multithreaded by BackGroundworkers and

> CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

EDIT: READ THIS IF YOU CAME HERE WITH THE SAME ERROR:

Nevermind, it's cause it isn't there, first it stores the 12th column into a string so it can be added later, but what I did is I added the code, it should get the text **but it wasn't there** it was still in a string

So, ***Make sure something is there***

Thanks anyway

Comment: and yes I've been searching this forum for the answer..

Comment: Is only "11" not working, or every value doesnt?

Comment: Have you verified there are there 12 items in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

In ListViews the first column displayed is the main item. The second column that you see is the first subitem. So if you see 12 columns in total, you will have only 11 subitems and the last valid subitem index will be `10`.

Comment: I know, I edited the post, I found the solution myself, thanks anyway!